# Cardinality of $A_k$ = {$a_i | a_i < a_k, i > k$} and $B_k$ = {$a_i | a_i > a_k, i<k$}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $(a_1,...,a_n)$ be a permutation of {$1,2,...,n$}.

Define

$A_k$ = {$a_i | a_i < a_k, i > k$} and $B_k$ = {$a_i | a_i > a_k, i<k$} 
for $1$$\leq$$k$$\leq$$n$.

Prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} |A_k|=\sum_{k=1}^{n} |B_k|$$

What idea would be useful? I though that using sign in permutation would be useful, but I can't develop proof based on that.

Comment: The left hand side counts all pairs $\left(i, k\right)$ satisfying $a_i < a_k$ and $i > k$. The right hand side counts all pairs $\left(i, k\right)$ satisfying $a_i > a_k$ and $i < k$. Do you see a bijection between the former and the latter?

Comment: I cant see the bijection, can you please explain it more?

Comment: I can now see it - is it a inversion in a permutation in both cases? So I should prove that it is injective and surjective, right?

Comment: You should define the bijection directly; what does it do to a pair?

Comment: Yes, it swaps i and k. So I define bijection f: A -> B as "swapping" of i and k. Hence I can claim that the cardinality of the two sets is equal.

Comment: Exactly. The bijection sends $\left(i, k\right)$ to $\left(k, i\right)$, and its inverse map does the same.